# C# Wait for Web Page to Load Before Scraping

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am trying to make a Windows Forms app that logs in another web application, navigates for a few steps (clicks) until it reaches a specific page and then scrape some info (names and addresses).

The problem is that I am using the DocumentCompletedEventHandler in order to have a page loaded before I execute the code for navigating to the next page (in order to reach the final web page).

When it fires, DocumentCompletedEventHandler fires multiple times.

When I reach the loggin page, it enters the credentials and then the message "Page loaded!" appears multiple times.
I press enter, it appears again.
Then it navigates to the next page and with that new page I have the same problem.

how can I make DocumentCompletedEventHandler to fire only once and not multiple times?

```
    private void loadEvent(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Page loaded!");
    }


    private void loadLogin(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var inputElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement i in inputElements)
        {
            if (i.GetAttribute("name").Equals("utilizator"))
            {
                i.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
            }
            if (i.GetAttribute("name").Equals("parola"))
            {
                i.Focus();
                i.InnerText = textBox2.Text;
            }
        }

        var buttonElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement b in buttonElements)
        {
            if (b.GetAttribute("name").Equals("Intra"))
            {
                b.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
       webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(loadEvent);


        var inputElements1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement i1 in inputElements1)
        {
            if (i1.GetAttribute("id").Equals("headerqstext"))
            {
                i1.Focus();
                i1.InnerText = textBox3.Text;
            }
        }

        var buttonElements1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach (HtmlElement b1 in buttonElements1)
        {
            if (b1.GetAttribute("title").Equals("Caută"))
            {
                b1.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(loadEvent);

    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://10.1.104.23/ecris_cdms/");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(loadLogin);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Look at selenium

Comment: `DocumentCompleted` event will raise for iframes as well. You can check e.Url to identify them.

Comment: I am trying to do it without selenium, but probably there is where I shall end up anyway. Thanks Barry

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
Uri last = null;
private void CompleteResponse(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(last != null && last != e.Url))
        return;
    //your code here
}
```